# How to connect to Azure SQL database with jTDS

Tags: java, azure, ssl, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I try to connect to Azure SQL with:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ExampleJTDS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Setting.
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433/DATABASE;ssl=off";
        String user = "USER@SERVER";
        String pass = "PASSWORD";

        // Declare the JDBC object.
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            // Establish the connection.
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, pass);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at run.ExampleJTDS.main(ExampleJTDS.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

If I force the encryption by substituting *ssl=off* with *ssl=require*, I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at run.ExampleJTDS.main(ExampleJTDS.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Interestingly, I can connect to the database from the same computer and with the same JDBC driver with [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (although without SSL - SQuirreL SQL manages to put the credentials into the first TDS packet and Azure accepts that). Hence, the problem should not be in the setting of firewalls.

Metadata:

- Server: Azure V12
- Driver: jtds-1.3.1
- JRE: 1.8.0_72-b15 (from Oracle)
- _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false
- security.provider.1: sun.security.provider.Sun
- OS: OS X 10.11.5
- SQuirreL SQL: 3.7.1

How can I connect to Azure SQL from Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to Azure SQL with JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743819/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think the issue was caused by the connection string which is the variable `connectionUrl` of your code. I have answered your similar question of the SO thread, please see [How to connect to Azure SQL with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743819/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc).

However, using jTDS instead of Microsoft JDBC driver for SQL Server has a little difference, you can refer to a note in [the step 3 of the tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple/#step-3-get-connection-string) to know it. As reference, I post the contento of the note here.

> **Note:**
>
> If you are using the JTDS JDBC driver, then you will need to add "ssl=require" to the URL of the connection string and you need to set the following option for the JVM "-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false". This JVM option disables a fix for a security vulnerability, so make sure you understand what risk is involved before setting this option.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.