# Error occurred while connecting with azure database using JDBC driver

Tags: java, azure, jdbc

Error occurred while connecting with azure database
Jul 07, 2016 8:42:32 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
    INFO: java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security
    Security providers: [SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS version 1.8, SunSASL version 1.8, XMLDSig version 1.8, SunPCSC version 1.8, SunMSCAPI version 1.8]
    SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust factories, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2)
    SSLContext provider services:
    [SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
    , SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> sun.security.ssl.RSASignature
    , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
    , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
      aliases: [PKIX]
    , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
    , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
      aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS10Context
      aliases: [SSLv3]
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.1 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS11Context
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1.2 -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLS12Context
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
      aliases: [SSL]
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
    , SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
    ]
    java.ext.dirs: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext

Sample Code used

```
package UtilityCreateSensorData;
// Use the JDBC driver  
import java.sql.*;  
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;  

public class SQLDatabaseConnection {

     // Connect to your database.  
    // Replace server name, username, and password with your credentials  
    public  void InsertData(String Value1,String Value2,String Value3,int Value4) {  

        String connectionString ="jdbc:sqlserver://test.database.windows.net:1433;database=test;user=TestUsername;password=TestPassword";  


        // Declare the JDBC objects.  
        Connection connection = null; 
        Statement statement = null;   
        ResultSet resultSet = null;  
        PreparedStatement prepsInsertProduct = null; 


        try {  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString); 
            // Create and execute an INSERT SQL prepared statement.  
           String insertSql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblAutomationTest] (DESC,MessageStart,MessageEnd,SenseCount) VALUES " + "(Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4);";  

           prepsInsertProduct = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);  
           prepsInsertProduct.execute();  

            // Retrieve the generated key from the insert.  
            resultSet = prepsInsertProduct.getGeneratedKeys();  

            // Print the ID of the inserted row.  
            while (resultSet.next()) { System.out.println("Generated: " + resultSet.getString(1));  
            }  

        }  
        catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        finally {  
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
         // Close the connections after the data has been handled.  
            if (prepsInsertProduct != null) try { prepsInsertProduct.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
        }  
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, it's only the exception information. Could you post more details include your code, environment & any helpful information? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to improve it. And there is a sample code for connecting SQL Azure in Java https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt720656.aspx. Any concern or update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Added the Complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your code, the issue was caused by the incorrect connection string for Azure SQL Database.

The correct format of connection string for SQL Azure is like below.

`jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<database-name>;user=<username>@<hostname>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`

That you can find it at the link `Show connection strings` of the right bar of the tab `DASHBOARD` on Azure old portal, or see it at the link Show database connection strings on Azure new portal.

You can refer to my answer for the SO thread [How to connect to Azure SQL with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743819/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc) to see the figures and codes, or see the offical article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-java-simple/.