# JDBC Broken Pipe Mac

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jdbc, azure-sql-database

It's very strange but I am repeatedly getting this issue everytime I attempt to connect to SQL Azure via JDBC.

Environment: Eclipse Oxygen, Mac Sierra 10.12.6, JDK 1.8.0_141

I see the following error:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Broken pipe (Write failed) ClientConnectionId:ac4ed2ba-4563-4f3b-9bcc-441bff9e45e1)
```

I am trying to create the connection in the most basic of ways, via context.xml as such:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/sqlazure"
auth="Container"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxIdle="30"
username="<user>
password="<password>
url="jdbc:sqlserver://<dbname>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<db>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
logAbandoned="true" />
```

In my servlet init() I am getting the datasource as such:

```
 ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/sqlazure");
```

And it is returning non-null.  However when I try to get a connection:

```
Connection con = ds.getConnection()
```

It hangs here and then times out with the broken pipe error.  I have also whitelisted the appropriate IP addresses in the Azure portal.

My SQLPro client is able to connect to the database and view its contents so shouldn't be any issue with username/password and connection string.

I have confirmed my hostname is set correctly. using:

```
scutil --get HostName
```

I've tried everything I can think of but still no luck.  I am starting to think that there is some issue with the Java runtime on OSX.  Anyone have any ideas ?

EDIT: I used the same exact files on Windows environment and JDK and did not see this issue.  So I am to believe this is Mac specific...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install Homebrew and Maven to make it work. Please follow instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was very similar with the other SO thread [How to connect to Azure SQL with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743819/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc). Please try its solution which comes from the same issue post at [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-221#comment=27-1826316).