# azure database and google spreadsheet connection error "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

Tags: azure, google-sheets, azure-sql-database

I tried many ways to fix this error :

`"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."`

**Code :**

```
 function AcessaVendas () {
   var URL = 'jdbc:sqlserver://servername:49159'
   var USER = 'visitant'
   var PASS = '*******'
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);  
   var stmt = conn.createStatement();
   stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
   var start = new Date(); 
   var rs = stmt.executeQuery( myquery());
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dados");
   ss.getRange('a2:h1000').clearContent();
   var cell = ss.getRange('a2');
   var row = 0;
   while (rs.next()) {
      for (var col = 0; col < 11; col++) {
        cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
var end = new Date();
Logger.log('Time elapsed: ' + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

First i have tried changing the azure servername for the server ip, then i tried adding the database name like,

```
db = "databasename"
URL = 'jdbc:mysql://servername:49159'+'/'+ db;
```

I also thought that maybe the database user that i have created in the sql server management studio could be the problem, because he has db_datareader role but i tried using the user with db_owner role and it also didn't work.

I also tried to put every Google App Server IPs whitelist range in the firewall of the azure server(one at once, or do i have to put ervery ip range at once?).

Could someone give me a help?

Comment: As far as I know, Azure SQL servers do not listen for connections on port 49159.

Comment: You need to change the connection string. Yours is trying to connect to a MySQL instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743819/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-with-jdbc.

Comment: I changed the connection string and this error apeared " We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Comment: I changed the connection string like this code:


String hostName = "xxxxx";
    String dbName = "petersqldb";
    String user = "peter@xxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxxx";
    String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s.database.windows.net:1433;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;", hostName, dbName, user, password);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

 and apeared  could not connect to server

Comment: So, you're using SQL Database service? If so: have you opened up the firewall port to allow your app to talk to it? If not, you won't be able to connect to the database.

Comment: in the azure firewall i entered all whitelisted ip range of goole,than i wrote the connection string into the  var url ,i received the error could not connect to server, than i tried this way 
"Url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db; same error

Comment: Can you try to connect with SQL Server Management Studio using your user credentials and having white-listed 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 ? Finally, are you using Azure MySQL or Azure SQL Database?

Comment: I'm using azure SQL Database, I have white-listed 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255, and used as url to cennect this "Url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db " and received as error "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password." i dont know anymore which is the correct sintax of the url , if its the connectstring, or just the servername/ip  and the port number or that plus the database name.

Comment: Can you try all the steps described in this document (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-azure-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide/)? In addition, can you make sure that port 1433 on your Google App server is open?